# Z3 - Formalising an array pattern matching

Tags: arrays, design-patterns, z3

I try to formalise a function that takes an array and an array list as parameter and return the index of the array in the list. I have tried very different approaches and get an "unknown" from Z3.

Here is some code I tried whereby neither the first nor the second axiom works (and several others I did not include here):

```
(declare-fun SameArray ((Array Int Real) (Array Int Real)) Bool)
(declare-fun Match ((Array Int Real) (Array Int (Array Int Real))) Int)

(assert (forall ((array1 (Array Int Real)) (array2 (Array Int Real)))
    (= 
      (SameArray array1 array2)
      (ite (forall ((i Int)) (= (select array1 i) (select array2 i) )) true false)
    )
  ) 
)

;(assert (forall ((pattern (Array Int Real)) (list (Array Int (Array Int Real))) )
;  (or
;    (exists ((index Int))
;      (and
;        (= (SameArray pattern (select list index)) true)
;        (forall ((j Int)) (or (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false) (>= j index)))
;        (= (Match pattern list) index)
;      )
;    )
;    (= (Match pattern list) (- 1))
;  )
;))

(assert (forall ((pattern (Array Int Real)) (list (Array Int (Array Int Real))) )
  (exists ((index Int))
    (and
      (= (Match pattern list) index)
      (or
        (and
          (= (SameArray pattern (select list index)) true)
          (forall ((j Int)) (or (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false) (>= j index)))
        )
        (= index (- 1))
      )
    )
  )
))

; Testing - SameArray

(declare-const a1 (Array Int Real))
(declare-const a2 (Array Int Real))

(assert (= (store a1 1 1.1) a1))
(assert (= (store a1 2 1.2) a1))
(assert (= (store a1 3 1.3) a1))

(assert (= (store a2 1 2.1) a2))
(assert (= (store a2 2 2.2) a2))
(assert (= (store a2 3 2.3) a2))

(assert (= (SameArray a1 a1) true))
(assert (= (SameArray a1 a2) false))

(check-sat)

; Testing - Match

(declare-const aAll (Array Int (Array Int Real)) )

(assert (= (store aAll 1 a2) aAll))
(assert (= (store aAll 2 a1) aAll))

(assert (= (Match a1 aAll) 2))

(check-sat)
```

Edit:
Even a quite simple dummy version does not work.
I have the pattern (P => Q)  and (not P => Q'). I do not have an idea why Z3 gives me an unknwon.

```
(assert (forall ((pattern (Array Int Real)) (list (Array Int (Array Int Real))) )
  (=>
    (forall ((j Int)) (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false))
    (= (Match pattern list) (- 1))
  )
))

(assert (forall ((pattern (Array Int Real)) (list (Array Int (Array Int Real))) )
  (=>
    (not (forall ((j Int)) (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false)))
    (= (Match pattern list) 1)
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved. The main problem was that the function `Match` was just declared and not defined and Z3 had problems to handle the additional axioms. While this was no problem for the `SameArray` function, the `Match` function failed. The right definition is as follows:

```
(define-fun SameArray ((array1 (Array Int Real)) (array2 (Array Int Real))) Bool
  (ite (forall ((i Int)) (= (select array1 i) (select array2 i) )) true false)
)


(define-fun Match ((pattern (Array Int Real)) (list (Array Int (Array Int Real))) ) Int
  (ite 
    (exists ((index Int))
      (and
        (= (SameArray pattern (select list index)) true)
        (forall ((j Int)) (or (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false) (>= j index)))
      )
    )
    1 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you deactivated both `MBQI` and `AUTO_CONFIG`, as done in [this variant](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/k4jm) of your code. There, you get an `unknown` for the first `check-sat` and an `unsat` for the second. If you comment both `set-option`s, you'll get `sat` and `unsat`.

The `unsat` is expected because the assertions made inside the `push`/`pop` scope contradict your first axiom.

Regarding the `unknown` vs `sat` I have to speculate a bit. According to my understanding, `MBQI` tries to find an interpretation for all uninterpreted  symbols, that is, it tries to find a model, such that the given assertions can be satisfied.

Without `MBQI`, Z3 relies on E-matching, that is, it does not try to find an interpretation for uninterpreted symbols. Z3 does try to find a contradiction, but the assertions made up to the point of the first `check-sat` don't contradict each other. Since the problem contains no derivable contradiction but uninterpreted symbols about which Z3 knows too little, all Z3 can report is `unsat`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I have not deactivated MBQI and AUTO_CONFIG and theirfore both are active. I would assume that the first check-sat is (sat) because their are no conflicting axioms. The second one should be also sat, because  the array a1 is at the second position of aAll. But I get "unknown" for both. What version of Z3 do you use to get (sat/unsat). My is 4.1 and I get (unknown/unknown).

Comment: @ChristianLiguda rise4fun reports 4.3 as the Z3 version. Did you try to disable MBQI and AUTO_CONFIG? Does it change the results?

Comment: I now tried it with Z3 4.3. I activated and deactivated MBQI and AUTO_CONFIG and get "unknown" for both (check-sat). Therefore the options does not affect the results of the above example.

Comment: @ChristianLiguda What about negating the goal you actually try to prove? Does that give you an unsat (which then means that your actual goal must be sat)?

Comment: Well the problem is, that Z3 can not handle the axioms for "Match". When I ask (check-sat) right after the axiom for "Match" I get an "unknown". Therefore all asserts that are related to Match are also unknown and the negation does not change that. I am afraid that the array pattern matching is harder than I thought it is.

Comment: @ChristianLiguda I disagree in "that Z3 cannot handle the axioms for 'Match'". As illustrated by the rise4fun-link I provided, it does report unsat when presented a contradiction.

Comment: The unsat is just related to the first axiom of the match function which you directly assert in the example. The second axiom provides the unknown. If you change the assertion in your example to "(assert (not (forall ((j Int)) (= (SameArray pattern (select list j)) false))))" you get an unknown as well.